# Is it possible to install different ASP.NET Core Frameworks in the same ASP.NET runtime container?

Tags: c#, asp.net, docker, dockerfile

I have the following `Dockerfile`

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0-focal

COPY ./appsettings.json /icon/Server-Files/

WORKDIR /icon

COPY ./* /icon/Server-Files/
CMD [ "dotnet", "Server-Files/Server.dll" ]
```

I do not have to build the project because I only have compiled `.dll` files with.

The image is built and is able to run. However I have a client that is trying to conduct some tasks in the server and I keep getting the following error:

```
| The specified framework can be found at:
icon42test        | It was not possible to find any compatible framework version
icon42test        | The framework 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.App', version '5.0.0' (x64) was not found.
icon42test        |   - The following frameworks were found:
icon42test        |       6.0.6 at [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
icon42test        | 
icon42test        | You can resolve the problem by installing the specified framework and/or SDK.
```

Is there a way to install the `5.0.0` framework into the container? I am unable to comprehend the distinction between the different `dotnet` images available on Docker Hub e.g. `aspnet`, `runtime-deps`, `runtime` etc.

Since I do not have the source code and only the compiled `.dll` files I am unable to understand which other frameworks I might need in the `aspnet` runtime container.

Comment: Have you tried using `FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0-focal` instead? Do you then get an error that it can't find 6.0?

Comment: @HansKilian Yes You are right. Get the version mis-match there if I revert to `5.0-focal` and my app completely crashes stating `6.0.0` is not found

Comment: @HansKilian would you happen to have some more information on this?

Comment: No, not really. I think I'd see if I could get all the DLLs to target the same framework rather than trying to install a second runtime version.

Comment: @HansKilian I found a solution for this. See the answer

Comment: @Shan-Desai such behavior usually represents some library versions mismatch. You need to fix that, cause otherwise you can have other problems.

Comment: @GuruStron I agree but please read my query where I clearly mention `I do not have to build the project because I only have compiled .dll files with.` Since I do not have the source code in my hand I cannot control the runtime frameworks versions

Comment: @Shan-Desai valid point, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might have found a solution for this:

It turns out that most of the `dotnet` information is stored in the `/usr/share/dotnet` directory within the respective containers for SDKs

Dockerfile syntax's `COPY` can be used in order to copy the relevant files from the container images to my current container using the following:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0-focal

## Add the relevant SDKs to this current runtime base image

COPY --from=mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:2.1 /usr/share/dotnet /usr/share/dotnet/
COPY --from=mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 /usr/share/dotnet /usr/share/dotnet/

# List out the available runtimes / SDKs
CMD ["dotnet", "--list-runtimes", "dotnet", "--list-sdks"]
```

The resultant output is as follows:

```bash
Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.30 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.30 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 5.0.17 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 6.0.6 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.30 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 5.0.17 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.6 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
```

Now you have the necessary runtimes / SDKs in the container.

Comment: That's can be a solution. But in general you can install in your container anything you want so in this case you can try installing runtime/sdk as described in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux). Note that 2.1 is out of support though and this way possibly not a solution.

Comment: Yes it is rather unfortunate that the compiled code base I have has to rely on 2.1 as well as 5.0 within the container. This is more of a legacy SDK for certain parts of the code that need to introduced from my side in order to keep the application running. @GuruStron